# Creating a vector of boost shared pointers

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have reached a problem and was wondering if someone could help me please.

In one of my classes (e.g. class1) I have a

`typedef boost::shared_ptr <class-one-object>`

`typedef std::vector<class-one-object>`

In another class (e.g. class2) I need to create a vector of this again, in order to iterate through this

`class-one-object`

so I was trying the following

```
class1::ImportTableObject& table = configPtr->getTable();    
std::vector<class1::class-one-object>::const_iterator* iter = table.begin();
```

This was throwing the following compilation error:

```
cannot convret `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::shared_ptr<class1::class-one-object>*, std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<class1::class-one-object>,
 std::alloctor<boost::shared_ptr<class1::class-one-object> > > to '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const class1::class-one-object*, std::vector<class1::class-one-object>
```

etc etc

Can anyone help me please?

thank you in advance

Comment: What helps me when I get errors like this is lining up the types one over the other. Then you notice that one is "normal_iterator*" and the other is just "normal_iterator".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`begin` doesn't return a pointer to an iterator, it returns an iterator.

```
std::vector<class1::class-one-object>::const_iterator iter = table.begin()
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that and it now complains about --  "std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<class1::class-one-object> > > > > to non-scalar type '__gn_cxx::normal_iterator etc etc

Comment: What is the exact type of `table`?

Comment: I have updated example above to show table, thank you so far btw

Comment: Eh? What is `class1::ImportTable`, and why aren't you using that type's iterators? Are you deriving from a `std::vector`? You're getting errors about type mismatches, and what you're showing isn't complete, so it's really hard to help you here. (Oh, and get a recent compiler with `auto` support, makes life much easier :) )

Comment: lol I wish I could switch compilers, but unfortunatley I cant make that call on this one :)

Comment: Can't help you here. On the face of it, that assignment doesn't make sense if `table` isn't exactly a `std::vector<class1::class-one-object>` or a typedef for that.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message one can conclude that you basically mixing containers: one containing shared pointers to 'class-one-object' and second containing 'class-one-object'. It looks like this should work:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<class1::class-one-object> >::const_iterator iter = table.begin();
```

but you probably would like to achieve something like this:

```
std::vector<class1::class-one-object> vec;
const class1::class-one-object* ptr = (*iter).get();
if (ptr)
    vec.push_back(*ptr);
```

Best regards.